# How to escape characters in include directives?

Tags: c++, c, include, c-preprocessor

Let's say I have a header file called `a"b.h` or `a>b.h`, how do I escape the `"` or `>` character in an include directive?

```
// this does not work
#include "a\"b.h"
```

Comment: The general best practice is to never write paths in #includes in the first place, even when they are relative. It's a source of problem and non-portable. Solve file locations by external means - these days typically by adding all files to a project in a programming IDE.

Comment: By the way the reason I'm asking this question is because I'm working on syntax highlighting for C code and I'd like to highlight include directives correctly. So renaming the file is not an answer that works for me.

Comment: @eyelash Well if you are making program exclusively for Windows you do not have to bother with those characters because they are forbidden in file names on Windows. See the: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names)

Comment: rename your include files to something that does not need escaping in thre first place

Comment: Also don't tag "C" and "C++". They are different languages (C++ only has some backward compatibilty with "C"). Use the tag that fits your compiler.

Comment: At least using such characters in filename is a very bad idea. If you can avoid, avoid.

Comment: I wouln't bother. There are probably only a few people in the world that are crazy enough to use \ and " in filenames.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`>` character is not allowed as part of filename when using `#include <filename>` directive (and respectively, `"` is not allowed as part of filename in `#include "filename"`). There is no standard way to escape  any characters in the sequence, any such feature would be a compiler extension. [cppreference link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include).

For the specific case of filename `a>b.h`, you can change it to `#include "a>b.h"` and it should work.

Filename `a"b.h` is out of luck - even in `#include <a"b.h>` it's implementation-defined how `"` character is treated (or if supported at all).

Aside from `"`, also using characters `'`, `\`, `//` or `/*` in filename part of `#include` directive is implementation-defined and may be unsupported.

Answer (score 2):

Digging into the depths of the C grammar, this syntax is defined in C17 6.4.7. The two valid syntax items that may appear behind `#include` are:

> *header-name:*
> `<` *h-char-sequence* `>`
> `"` *q-char-sequence* `"`

These consist of *h-char* and *q-char* items respectively. The standard then explicitly forbids `>` and `"` characters inside the inclusion strings:

> *h-char:*
> any member of the source character set except the new-line character and `>`

> q-char:
> any member of the source character set except the new-line character and `"`

This is portable behavior that any C compiler must follow.

However, you could use the `>` inside an `#include "header.h"`.

Answer (score 1):

Allowed characters are defined in [lex.charset](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.charset#1). You may use any of these characters as long as they do not break the parsing: [lex.header](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.header).

In your case you may need to add the include path and try this:

```
#include "a>b.h"
```